# HttpServletRequest unable to perform getParameter operation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

Here is the code in JSP:

```
<li>  
   <input type="hidden" name="testID" value="mot0000001">
   <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoadTestDetails">Sample Test</a>
</li>
```

Here `LoadTestDetails` is the name of servlet. The servlet is called but on printing the `testID`, through `out.println(request.getParameter("testID"));` i got output: `null`.

Comment: Post your servlet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the link, your browser simply performs an HTTP `GET` request. The value of the hidden `input` field will not be sent along.

To get the effect you want, either submit a form with a javascript or append the value as a URL parameter like this:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoadTestDetails?testID=mot0000001">
    Sample Test</a>
```

Form submit has a side effect of disturbing the Browser navigation (back button), the URL-encoded parameter will be visible in the URL. Choose what you prefer.

**Example form submit with Javascript:**

```
<form id="myForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoadTestDetails"
            method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="testID" value="mot0000001">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
        Sample Test</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible without passing appending parameter to url?

Comment: @M.S. Yes it is. Please read my answer, I mentioned 2 methods. If you don't want it to include in the URL, submit a form with Javascript.

Comment: Edited and added example how to submit a form with Javascript.